# some parts of Qrect missing

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

I'm trying to move a circle(my class inherits QGraphicsItem) by using QTimer in keyPressEvent function.
here is my class:

```
class Shape :public QGraphicsObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
   Shape();
   QRectF boundingRect() const;
   void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
   void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
}
```

and the boundingRect and paintfunction:

```
QRectF Shape::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0,0,30,30);
}

void Shape::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{

   QRectF circle=boundingRect();
    //painter->setClipRect( option->exposedRect );
    QBrush brush(QColor(Qt::darkGreen));
    painter->setPen(QColor(Qt::darkGreen));
    painter->setBrush(brush);
    painter->drawEllipse(circle);
}
```

and this is how the timer works:

```
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_1){
        if(!start){
            timer->stop();
            timer=NULL;
        }
        setScale(1);
        timer=new QTimer(scene());
        connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(moveRightLeft()));
        timer->start(2);
        start=false;
}

void Shape::moveRightLeft()
{
    if(scene()->collidingItems(this).isEmpty()==true){//no collision
        setPos(x()+dir,y());
    }
    else{
        dir=-(dir);
        setPos(x()+dir,y());
    }
}
```

The problem is when the key is pressed after a few seconds some parts of the circle is missing depending on the direction its moving.Even prepareGeometryChange() and update() didn't work.[this is the shape of the circle while moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrzVE.png) 
thanks for your help!

Comment: The only thing I see is that the pen width of 1 will be drawing outside of the object's bounding rectangle. A width of 1 will actually be averaged over two scene coordinates. Even so, I would expect that to cause drawing artifacts as it moved, not the truncation you see. Still, try setting the pen as "setPen (Qt::NoPen)". Since the line and brush are the same solid color, it won't make a significant visual difference. You shouldn't need to call "update" or "prepareGeometryChange" when just setting the position, so it's fine without them.

Comment: @goug thanks for your comment but setting no pen didn't worked :(

Comment: Is there any possibility that something else that's white is drawing over the top of the circle? Also, just a long shot, but maybe put a "prepareGeometryChange" call in your object's constructor? I'm not accustomed to a hard-coded bounding rectangle, and I'm wondering if that's confusing the scene somehow.

Comment: @goug I don't know what is wrong with this..there's only a circle and 4 lines creating a rectangle...for the first few seconds it works perfectly and  if I set the timer to be repeated every 6 or higher seconds ,this truncation doesn't happen...and prepareGeometryChange didn't work.

Comment: of course I think prepareGeometryChange() in the constructor made it happen less than before

Comment: I can't reproduce the movement, so i apparently don't have enough code from the above. However, did you call the base class constructor from your constructor:  Shape::Shape () : QGraphicsObject {...}